# Trigonometric factoring

Tags: factoring

Very next question, no idea what to do...

I am suppose to factor  $2\sin^2x + 3\sin x+1$ .

I figure this is pretty simple so I do $(2\sin x)(2\sin x)+3 \sin x+1$ .

For some reason this is incorrect (not sure why) and they give $(2\sin x+1)(\sin x+1)$ which I did verify gives me the original but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: What you did is not incorrect (apart from a 2), but it is not a factorization of the whole expression: you are supposed to get a product of two factors $2\sin^2x + 3\sin x+1 = (something)(anotherthing)$ and your approach didn't lead you there.

Comment: @Adam: At some time, you learned how to "factor" $2y^2+3y+1$.  You got $(2y+1)(y+1)$.  Now let $y=\sin x$ and remember that $\sin^2 x$ means $(\sin x)^2$.  You end up with $(2\sin x +1)(\sin x +1)$.  Maybe check by multiplying out.

Comment: @Adam: You are having trouble with basic mathematical conventions.  For example, $2\sin^2 x$ means $2\times (\sin x)^2$.  From what you wrote, you interpreted it as $(2 \times \sin x)^2$.  Now I will admit that the notation $\sin^2 x$ for the square of the sine of $x$, is not best possible.  But it is nearly universally used, so one has to become accustomed to it.

Comment: Yeah I know I am horrible at math, I should probably change my major out of engineering.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately if you end up liking math), you're going to be doing a LOT and I mean A LOT of math. Half your classes if not more are going to be math classes if you're degree is in engineering lol.

Comment: I like math, I just wish I wasn't so terrible at it. I practice but I really need to learn to practice without getting stuck every other problem and pissed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $2sin^2(x) + 3sin(x) + 1$ as a whole function similar to $2x^2 + 3x + 1$ and see if it makes sense now.

Comment: I tried that and I have no idea what to do, seems like I forgot everything I learned about math a couple months ago.

Comment: Well, can you factor $2x^2 + 3x + 1$?

Comment: I am having trouble thinking about how to do it since I can't complete the square or any of the obvious methods I know. Trial and error I suppose. I got (2x+1)(x+1) with trial and error.

Comment: Well, what are the factors of 1? There are none, so obviously the factored form will be $( $_$ + 1)( $_$ + 1)$ since both the signs in the polynomial are positive. So what combinations will give you a $3x$ when you add them together and also give you $2x^2$? $2x$ and $1x$ (or just $x$). So you end up with what?

Comment: Thanks I got it, unfortunately I got stuck on the very next problem.

Answer (score 3):

Adam:

Looking at: $2\sin^2x + 3\sin x+1$

Note that $\sin^2x$ means nothing more than $(\sin x)^2$, so you can rewrite your expression as $2(\sin x)^2 + 3(\sin x) + 1$.  Then, as others have suggested, set $y = \sin x$ --> then substituting into the original expression, we have $2y^2+ 3y + 1$.  Once you factor that, remember to replace every $y$ with $\sin x$,  and you should have the factored expression that matches your book's answer.

Comment: Yes, of course, @Babak ! (Sorry I didn't catch your message earlier!)

Comment: Which expression do you use when you are scaring cause of very horrible things and you feel this state on your skin? I want this word. I saw one of Judy Foster's recent work and somewhere I felt she told a word which I didn't catch.

Comment: Let me think about it...I know what you mean, I simply can't recall this moment what term Jodie Foster used. Sometimes, people say: "I was so scared, that my skin was crawling!"

Comment: Bingo! I think she said something like it. Thanks so much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried multiplying out the book answer to see what you get?  Again, the fact that you have $\sin x$ is not important:  $2y^2+3y+1=(2y+1)(y+1)$.  Your answer is not in a factored form, nor is it correct as $(2\sin x)(2\sin x)=4\sin^2 x$